# Return the index of the largest number in the array

Tags: java, arrays

Question: Write a method called largest which takes the array nums3 as a parameter.  It finds the largest of the numbers in the array and returns its index as the value of the method.

So I know that if I return largest, that's the value, but how can I return i, the index? When i compile, i get Error: cannot find the symbol i.

```
public static int largest(int[] nums3)
{
    int largest = nums3[0];
    for(int i=0; i < nums3.length; i++)
    {
        if(nums3[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = nums3[i];
        }

        }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You answered your own question: if you want to return the index you return i.

Comment: @fr1tz he needs to return the index of the largest number

Comment: I might give you a hint: create a variable `int largestIndex;`

Comment: You are keeping track of the largest number... do the same exact thing for the index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it can be saving largest index, not value. You also need to return some value in case of empty array:

```
public static int largest(int[] nums3)
{
    if (nums3.length == 0) { return -1; } 
    int largestIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < nums3.length; i++)
    {
        if(nums3[i] > nums3[largestIndex])
        {
            largestIndex = i;
        }

    }
    return largestIndex;
}
```